# Setting up Custom 404 error page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

I am trying to redirect my users to a custom error page for 404 page not found error. I created a `redirect.html` and placed it in `layouts/1033/` folder and executed the following script

```
$webapp =Get-SPWebApplication <URL>
$webapp.FileNotFoundPage = "redirect.html"
$webapp.update()
```

While the redirection is working good when I hit `http://<webapp>/Pages/DoesntExist.aspx`

But when I try some urls like

```
http://<webapp>/Pages/ExistingPage.dfjkdf
```

or

```
http://<webapp>/Pages/asdf/qewr
```

instead of redirection, the contents of `redirect.html` is displayed in the browser.

Below is the contents of redirect.html

```
<!-- _localBinding -->
<!-- _lcid="1033" _version="" -->
<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="0" /> 
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/_layouts/spsredirect.aspx?noscript=1" />
</noscript> 
<script language="javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/core.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">                              
    var redirectURL = "/Pages/Custom404.aspx";  
    STSNavigate(redirectURL);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any step I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the redirect.html file code as below.

```
<!-- _localBinding -->
<!-- _lcid="1033" _version="" -->
<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="0" /> 
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/Pages/Custom404.aspx?noscript=1" />
</noscript> 
<script language="javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/core.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">                              
    var redirectURL = "/Pages/Custom404.aspx";
    STSNavigate(redirectURL);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Or create an aspx file named as Custom404.aspx under "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS".

Replace the following line of code in redirect.html file.

```
var redirectURL = "/Pages/Custom404.aspx";
```

with

```
var redirectURL = "/_layouts/Custom404.aspx";
```

Refer to: [How to create Custom 404 Error Page in SharePoint 2010](http://dishasharepointworld.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-custom-404-error-page-in.html)